# What do I need to do a custom ROM from scratch?

Tags: android, rom, custom-rom

I already have the kernel of my cell phone and the latest version of google git android, the linux environment and the android studio, but how can I create a custom rom, sort of get the pixel expirience source code and make my changes.

soure: https://android.googlesource.com/

kernel: https://lenovomobilesupport.lenovo.com/br/pt/products/phones/k-series/k5/downloads/DS112641

model: A6020l36

Answer (score 0):

https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements

Essentially you do the following:

1. Establish your build environment.
2. Checkout the source code for the branch of Android you want to build.
3. Obtain binaries for your device and put them in the proper location in the source tree.
4. Make your source changes and/or apply any patches you desire.
5. Build the ROM images using make.
6. Flash your device.
7. (Optional) Flash Google Apps if desired.

I know I'm simplifying the process, but these are the major milestones you will encounter.